# SELECT ERROR 229 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions, windows-10

I know that this has come up before but none of the previous questions are quite the same as mine.

When I remotely log into our live database server and try to either view the tables in object explorer or run a select statement. I get:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'extended_properties', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229)

What makes my instance different that the others on Stack is that my DBA is using the same login information as I am. His works fine. Mine doesn't.

What's more, my instance was working properly. Last week I got a new PC that has Windows 10 on it. I hope that that doesn't have anything to do with the issue I am having.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Are you both running the same version of SSMS?

Comment: When you "remotely log into" do you mean RDP or are you referring to using SSMS to remotely manage the SQL database?  If you RDP to the server do you get the same error?

Comment: I was referring to SSMS, sorry. I don't have access to Remote Desktop into our server.